# How to simulate IAmazonLambda.InvokeAsync using the test UI in the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am using the AWS SDK for .NET and am able to invoke a Lambda from code via the `IAmazonLambda.InvokeAsync` method ([doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lambda/MLambdaILambdaInvokeAsyncInvokeAsyncRequest.html)), passing it a request parameter that specifies the payload with the `IAmazonLambda` client providing the credentials.

I also have the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio set up in VS 2015, so that I can right-click on my project, upload to AWS Lambda, and get the following testing view after the upload succeeds:

[image]

You can click the "Invoke" button here to invoke the Lambda. You need to enter the input to the Lambda as JSON in the "Sample input" box.

I don't know what the JSON format of the sample input should be to simulate my `InvokeAsync` call. The example request formats provided (in the dropdown box) are for things like DynamoDB triggers or Scheduled Events, none for the SDK `InvokeAsync`.

Part of the input to `InvokeAsync` is a user-defined payload, and I obviously have this, but I don't know how to specify the user credentials, or what the overall JSON structure should be.

So: what is the format of the JSON data I should put in the sample input box above to simulate an `IAmazonLambda.InvokeRequest` call?

Comment: Question is Super hard to understand. Lambda is just a function call. What do you mean simulate? You just call the function in a unit test...

Comment: @Phil as noted I have no trouble calling the Lambda from code. However I'd like to use the UI in the AWS Toolkit for VS where you can invoke a Lambda with test JSON input. This UI gives different example JSON formats to simulate different triggers for a Lambda. There is no example to simulate an InvokeLambda.

Comment: @Phill, I've added a screenshot and expanded on the question -- hopefully it is more clear now.